# Pass the information from CKRecord to user defined class type

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit

I have to following class type

```
class Recipe {
 
  private let id: CKRecord.ID
  let name: String
  let coverPhoto: CKAsset?
  
  init?(record: CKRecord, database: CKDatabase) {
    guard
      let name = record["name"] as? String
    else { return nil }
    id = record.recordID
    
    self.name = name
    coverPhoto = record["coverPhoto"] as? CKAsset
  }
```

and in my viewcontroller, I want to display list of names that I fetched from cloudkit. So, i am trying to find a way to convert CKRecord to my class type Recipe.

I tried this but failed

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "GroceryItem", predicate: NSPredicate(value:true))
        database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { [weak self] records, error in
            guard let records = records,error == nil else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.items = records.compactMap({ $0.value as? Recipe }) // gives error ambigous value
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
              
            }
        }
```

**Records** is the fetched variable from cloudkit as CKRecord

**items** is array of Recipe, [Recipe]

I want to transfer the data from **records** to **items**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast the type. You have to call `init`.

First remove the `database` parameter from the init method, it’s obviously not needed

```
init?(record: CKRecord) { …
```

Then replace

```
self?.items = records.compactMap({ $0.value as? Recipe })
```

with

```
self?.items = records.compactMap(Recipe.init)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I already had my init so it worked like a charm.